# How do I force line-breaks in my index?

Tags: indexing

I have a big book with a lot of index entries. I'm getting some overprinting in the index, like this:

[image]

I've created a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
This is the first page.
\index{European Organization for Nuclear Research (CERN)}
\index{fable book}
\index{fable forger}
\index{fable-framing}
\index{fable play}
\index{fable teller}
\index{fabrication tax}
\index{fabric spring}
\index{fabric tire}
\index{face-about}
\index{face-ache}
\index{face ague}
\index{face angle}
\index{face-arbor}
\index{face bath}
\index{face-bedded}
\index{face bone}
\index{face brick}
\index{face card}
\index{face-centered}
\index{face chuck}
\index{face cleat}
\index{face cog}
\index{face cord}
\index{face cover}
\index{face cream}
\index{faced-lined}
\index{face dresser}
\index{face dressing}
\index{face enamel}
\index{face gear}
\index{face guard}
\index{face hammer}
\index{face-harden}
\index{face joint}
\index{face lathe}
\index{face lifting}
\index{face mask}
\index{face massage}
\index{face milling}
\index{face mite}
\index{face mold}
\index{face molder}
\index{face-off}
\index{face-on}
\index{face paint}
\index{face painter}
\index{face painting}
\index{face par}
\index{face pit}
\index{faceplate coupling}
\index{faceplate jaw}
\index{face powder}
\index{face presentation}
\index{face rouge}
\index{face-saving}
\index{face side}
\index{face spanner}
\index{face specialist}
\index{face sponge}
\index{face stone}
\index{face string}
\index{face towel}
\index{face urn}
\index{face value}
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Without the `12pt`, the index looks like this:
[image]

With the `12pt`, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm compiling this with:

```
$ latexmk  -pdfxe -bibtex idemo.tex ; open idemo.pdf
```

(I get the same results with `-pdf` instead of `pdfxe`)

Comment: line breaking would be allowed by default perhaps you want to set raggedright or allow more inter-word stretch or ....  with no example code can't really say a lot why that particular line didn't break, but obviously you can't hyphenate `(CERN)`

Comment: fascinating. My MWE did not have this problem, but when I included all of my book packages, it did. Let me do a binary search and figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: Okay, @DavidCarlisle, I've added a MWE, and I do not understand what's going on!

Comment: it of course isn't really the 12pt any more than it is the word CERN. Whether there is a feasibly line break in any line depends on the font, the page size the words used ....

Comment: Right, but my index font is set at the end with the `\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `imakeidx`, which internally uses `multicol` instead of the standard two-column format. It also doesn't require a separate run of `makeindex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\indexsetup{othercode=\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
This is the first page.
\index{European Organization for Nuclear Research (CERN)}
\index{fable book}
[...other index entries omitted...]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also consider three column format:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=3]
\indexsetup{othercode=\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
[...the rest is the same...]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really related to indexing or the document class option, just that some sequences of words are hard to break at some line widths.

Using either

```
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\raggedright
```

or

```
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\sloppy
```

allows it to break without being over full and sticking in to the next column, the effects are diffeent though you could choose which you prefer.

Comment: But why are the column widths changing with the `12pt` option?

Comment: The `\sloppy` does the trick!

Comment: @vy32 they are slightly wider as the standard classes try to make sure you don't have too many characters on a line, so at a default 12pt you can have a slightly larger line  width.